# Convert wmv webcasts to divx avi files

Tags: video, conversion, avi, wmv, divx

I need a free tool which will allow me to convert WMV files into avi (Divx) files that I can play on my Mvix player.

I am basically downloading microsoft webcasts and would like to watch them on my media player.

Answer (score 1):

[STOIK Video Converter 2.1.3 (free)](http://www.stoik.com/products/svc/)

> Convert AVI, WMV, DV  files in all possible combinations. Pick up one or multiple source video files, select output audio and video settings using preinstalled or custom profiles, and convert to single or multiple output video files. Now supports DivX + MP3 AVI, Windows Media 9, multiple file conversion, and file merging.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have DIVX codecs installed in your machine (which you'll surely have, as you watch these files I guess) you can also try the free Mediacoder. A converter for many formats. http://www.mediacoderhq.com